# Problems booting from USB drive

Tags: linux, boot, debian, bios, usb-flash-drive

Recently I decided to install Debian on my USB drive. I downloaded the ISO file (SHA256 checksum verified), burned it to a DVD and used that to install Debian.
The installation finished successfully, and I was told to remove the DVD and restart the computer. However, my computer can't boot from my USB drive. It gets stuck at the second booting screen, which actually shows a line indicating that my USB is connected: "USB Storage Device: SanDisk", and a line at the bottom: "Verifying DMI Pool Data". After this the flashing caret moves to a new line, and the boot stops. Nothing changes afterwards.

I tried several solutions, but none of them worked. These include:

1. Changing the first boot device to USB-HDD or USB-ZIP. Same results.
2. Changing the hard drive boot priority (and booting from hard disk as well). My USB doesn't show up in the list. Only my hard drive's name and an item called "bootable add-in cards" are included. (Tried changing the order and the computer still boots from the internal hard disk)
3. Resetting BIOS, then set the appropriate boot priority again.
4. Plugging in my USB before switching on the computer.
5. Plugging in my USB into another ports.

One interesting thing I noticed is that my USB drive feels quite warm after waiting for around 5 minutes. Not sure if there is any data transfer, though.

Any suggestions on how to boot from my USB drive?